# LinearLayout's width in ListView goes beyond Screen width

Tags: android, android-listview, universal-image-loader

I'm running into an issue that I can't seem to fix. I have a number of pictures that I want to show users in two different formats, one format, "list", showing the picture spanning the whole width of the screen and one format, "grid", showing a grid with 3 pictures in a row. To do this, I have a header of additional information that will persist switching between the "grid" and "list". I put this all in a ListView and allowed user to toggle with a button (contained in ListView's header) and simply changed the adapter to put into the ListView.  The "list" works great, but when I switch to "grid", it appears that only one image shows up with a bunch of space to the right. The GridLayout would have been better for this, but given the requirement, I didn't see why the ListView wouldn't work for me. Here is the layout:

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/event_detail_gridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/grid_image_1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:onClick="showPictureDetail" />


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/grid_image_2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:onClick="showPictureDetail" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/grid_image_3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:onClick="showPictureDetail" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I'm using the universal image loader as seen below

```
    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context.getApplicationContext())
    .threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 2)
    .memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache())
    .enableLogging()
    .build();

    imageLoader.init(config);

    options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
    .showStubImage(R.drawable.placeholder)
    .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_INT)
    .cacheInMemory()
    .cacheOnDisc()
    .displayer(new SimpleBitmapDisplayer())
    .build();

    imageLoader.displayImage(url, imageView, options);
```

I see the image loader loading the pictures in at the full screen width, but would figure android:weightSum="3" and android:layout_weight="1" would take care of the larger picture. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Just a guess - remove the `android:adjustViewBounds` attribute from your `ImageButton` declarations in the layout file. Either that or set it to `"false"`.

Comment: So what's your problem? Can you attach screenshots?